# When the arithmetic operations or functions are executed in Oracle database?

Tags: query-optimization, oracle12c, database-administration, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

When I execute a query including arithmetic operations or functions in the select statement, when are they executed in query execution? I mean, is it before the ORDER BY, HAVING and GROUP BY clauses? Or after all these?

An example query : `select example_function(column_name), column2*34 from table;`

Comment: It depends on where in the query those functions appear. Please [edit] your question to show the query you are analyzing. And, be aware that the database server caches the values of [deterministic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/DETERMINISTIC-clause.html#GUID-6AECC957-27CC-4334-9F43-0FBE88F92654) so it doesn't have to re-evaluate them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @O.Jones . It should be inside the select statement. But I also wonder in other places like where clause etc.